# How does scipy calculate the binomial CDF so fast?

Tags: binomial-distribution, computational-statistics, scipy

I ran scipy.stats.binom.cdf(500006, 1000000, 0.5) and it took less than a milisecond. This is crazy as binomial CDF involves summing up a bunch of binomial coefficients. What approximation algorithm goes behind the implementation? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a connection between the binomial cdf and the beta cdf. As a result, most software implementations of binomial cdf [use a call to a regularized incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). That's what scipy.stats does also, as it says in the documentation of `special.bdtr` (which is what gets called when you ask for a binomial cdf)

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.bdtr.html